# Grails Spring Security plugin - secure everything except root path

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

Due to some external reasons (there are some filters defined in web.xml applied only to some paths), I need to achieve the following (simplified) scenario:

- `/` path doesn't require authentication and redirects to '/secured'
- `/secured` requires authentication
- `/public1`, `/public2`, etc. don't require authentication
- everything else (`/**`) requires authentication

To achieve this, there's a `filterChain` defined in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [..., 'myAuthenticationFilter']
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
  '/': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-myAuthenticationFilter',
  '/public1/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-myAuthenticationFilter',
  '/public2/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-myAuthenticationFilter',
  '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS'
]
```

There is, however, a problem with matching the `/` path. I tried `'/'` and `''`. I can match this path with `'/*'`, but it matches more URLs, which is not what I need.

I cannot require users to be authenticated when they access `/`, because redirect to `/secured` has to be done in all cases, and authentication requirement is, let's say, "externally provided" only for the `/secured` and a few other paths.

Is there any good way to achieve this behavior?

I'm using Grails 2.0.4 with Spring Security Core plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In Grails there is simpler way to define these rules. You could use [interceptUrlMap](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#5.2%20Simple%20Map%20in%20Config.groovy) or requestmap.

For example, you can define your security configurations in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
   '/secured/**':    ['ROLE_ADMIN','IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
   '/public1/**':   ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/public2/**':   ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/js/**':        ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/css/**':       ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/images/**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/login/**':     ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/logout/**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/':            ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
   '/**':            ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']          //put this as the last item
]
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = "/secured"   //redirect `/` access to `/secured`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use URLMapping to associate a specific controller and action with the `/` URL? You can then secure everything except that specific controller/action pair.